# I cant insert long string Id with underscore(_) in my database

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

mycode:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

if(isset($_POST['id_feuille']) && isset($_POST['nom_feuille']) ){  

    $id_feuille = $_POST['id_feuille'];
    $nom_feuille = $_POST['nom_feuille'];

    var_dump($id_feuille);   
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($nom_feuille);

   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "**UPDATE Parametres SET id_feuille = ? AND nom_feuille = ? WHERE type = N**");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $id_feuille,$nom_feuille); // Error is on this line

    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement); 


}
}
```

Result:
[image]

- the code insert 0 or 1 in id_feuille column
- the image show the example of id that i want insert

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2jUt.png)

Comment: Should there be quotes round the N in `type = N");` as this will currently assume a column called N.

Comment: (y) the code work but still insert 0 or 1 in id_feuille column

Comment: Check what your database columns are defined as.

Comment: table(Parametres) in my database:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2jUt.png

Comment: @KhalilEl Please edit your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` statement of your table. Also use `mysqli_error()` to see the error you get from MySQL.